# Flutter SnackBar is attached to wrong Scaffold

Tags: flutter

I have two screens where the second screen is pushed above the first with `Navigator.push()` and the second screen is partial transparent. I want to display a `SnackBar`, but it isn't really visible. It looks like the `ScaffoldMessenger` chooses the wrong of the two `Scaffold`s to attach the `Snackbar`. This leads to the effect that the `SnackBar` collides with the `TextInput` and it is also not fully visible. But this bad behavior is only the case as long as the soft keyboard is open. If the keyboard is closed, everything works fine. It seems like the open keyboard tells the `ScaffoldMessenger` to choose the `Scaffold` from the second screen to display the `SnackBar`.

How can I achieve that the `SnackBar` is shown normally in the sense of is attached to the `Scaffold` of screen 2 while the keyboard is open? The expected behavior is that the `Snackbar` isn't displayed transparent.

### Keyboard open -> SnackBar is attached to Scaffold of screen 1 -> Bad

[image]

### Keyboard closed -> SnackBar is attached to Scaffold of screen 2 -> Good

[image]

### GIF showing the complete workflow

[image]

### My code (fully executable)

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:keyboard_utils/keyboard_listener.dart';
import 'package:keyboard_utils/keyboard_utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide KeyboardListener;

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage());
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Title')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[const Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
            Text('$_counter', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
                  opaque: false, // push route with transparency
                  pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => const Screen2(),
                ));
              },
              child: const Text('navigate'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => setState(() => _counter++),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Screen2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Screen2> createState() => _Screen2State();
}

class _Screen2State extends State<Screen2> {
  final _keyboardUtils = KeyboardUtils();
  late int _idKeyboardListener;
  final focusNode = FocusNode();

  bool isEmojiKeyboardVisible = false;
  bool isKeyboardVisible = false;
  double _keyboardHeight = 300;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _idKeyboardListener = _keyboardUtils.add(
        listener: KeyboardListener(
          willHideKeyboard: () {
            if (isKeyboardVisible) {
              isKeyboardVisible = false;
              isEmojiKeyboardVisible = false;
            }

            setState(() {}); // show correct Icon in IconButton
          },
          willShowKeyboard: (double keyboardHeight) async {
            if (Platform.isAndroid) {
              _keyboardHeight = keyboardHeight + WidgetsBinding.instance.window.viewPadding.top / WidgetsBinding.instance.window.devicePixelRatio;
            } else {
              _keyboardHeight = keyboardHeight;
            }

            isKeyboardVisible = true;
            isEmojiKeyboardVisible = true;
            setState(() {});
          },
        )
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _keyboardUtils.unsubscribeListener(subscribingId: _idKeyboardListener);

    if (_keyboardUtils.canCallDispose()) {
      _keyboardUtils.dispose();
    }

    focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> onEmojiButtonPressed() async {
    if(isEmojiKeyboardVisible){
      if(isKeyboardVisible){
        FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
        isKeyboardVisible = false;
      } else {
        focusNode.unfocus();
        await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1));
        if(!mounted) return;
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
      }
    } else {
      assert(!isKeyboardVisible);
      setState(() {
        isEmojiKeyboardVisible = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold( // wrapping with ScaffoldMessenger does NOT fix this bug
      backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Expanded(child: SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 200,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(isKeyboardVisible || !isEmojiKeyboardVisible ? Icons.emoji_emotions_outlined : Icons.keyboard_rounded),
                        onPressed: onEmojiButtonPressed,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                          focusNode: focusNode,
                        ),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.send),
                        onPressed: () => ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('A snack!'))),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            ),
            Offstage(
              offstage: !isEmojiKeyboardVisible,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: _keyboardHeight,
                child: Container(color: Colors.red),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Dependencies

```yaml
keyboard_utils: ^1.3.4
```

### What I've tried

I tried to wrap the `Scaffold` of `Screen2` with a `ScaffoldMessenger`. This doesn't fix my problem. In that case, no `SnackBar` was shown at all if the keyboard was open.

Edit: I also created an GitHub issue for that but I don't expect an answer soon: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/105406#issuecomment-1147194647

Edit 2: A workaround for this issue is to use `SnackBarBehaviod.floating` and a bottom margin, for example:

```dart
SnackBar(
  content: Text('A snack!'),
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 350.0),
  behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
)
```

But this is not a satisfying solution.

Comment: Why do you use 2 different scaffold? If the app requires you to show 2 different screens make the second class return a container instead of a scaffold and overlay it on top of first widget.

Comment: This isn't a good solution which scale. In my real application I have lots of `Scaffold`s which not have only different `body`'s.

Comment: Yeah i agree. But if it's going to be only an overlay you can return a container. Also if you are overlapping a scaffold then showSnackBar also to be invoked from the overlay scaffold

Comment: As you can see in my code the `SnackBar` is onvoked from the second screen. But that does not matter since Flutter introduces the `ScaffoldMessenger` API. `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)` will always call the `ScaffoldMessengerState` that comes implicitly with the `MaterialApp` at the root of the widget tree.